# node.js app for live HTML code preview

Tags: node.js, preview

I am looking for a node.js app I came across some time ago on github. It shows the results of html code from a textarea.

Does anyone know of this or have any good alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by "shows the results of html code from a textarea"? Is a user typing something which is transmitted in real-time to some other users.. ?

Comment: No, just to the user. Similar to http://jsbin.com/ezuta4/2

Comment: Node.js runs on the server, the example runs on the client. Where's the relevance?

Comment: @JanJongboom, I'm not sure if it had server functionality, that is what I will expand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) by any chance? (or something similar)